# Mysql Group By and Order by giving strange results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Im developing a chat tool and im having problems with the sql returning the right results with group by and order by. The table has a structure shown below;

tablename: chat

```
id | from | to | sent | read | message
```

'from' and 'to' are a signed integers (userids)
'sent' is a timestamp when the message was sent.
'message' is text msg
'read' is an int (0 for unread, 1 for read).

im trying to return a list of the most recent messages grouped by users

eg

```
id         from     to      message        sent    read
7324       21      1       try again    1349697192  1
7325       251       1     yo whats up  1349741502  0
7326       251       1     u there      1349741686  0
```

should return this after the query

```
    id      from    to     message      sent        read
7326        251     1        u there    1349741686   0
7324        21      1       try again    1349697192  1
```

here is my query

```
$q ="SELECT chat.to,chat.read,chat.message,chat.sent,chat.from FROM `chat` WHERE chat.to=$userid GROUP BY chat.from ORDER BY chat.sent DESC,chat.read ASC LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$count).",$count";
```

it doesnt return the desired results;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a subquery which determines the latest `sent` by `users` then join it with `chat` table.

```
SELECT  a.*                   -- this will list all latest rows from chat table
FROM    `chat` a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT `from`, `to`, MAX(sent) maxSent
            FROM `chat`
            GROUP BY `from`, `to`
        ) b ON a.`from` = b.`from` AND
                a.`to` = b.`to` AND
                a.sent = b.maxSent
-- WHERE ....                 -- add your condition(s) here
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63bdf/1)

Comment: in your query, i dont see a part where you can specify the 'to' eg in my example $userid. check this out to see what i mean http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca5a0/1

Comment: @SirLojik [see this: added WHERE and ORDER BY clause](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca5a0/5)

Comment: everything seems to look okay except that the 'sent' is not ordered

Comment: @SirLojik so how do you want to sort the records? :)

Comment: fixed it with this             $q ="SELECT  a.* FROM `chat` a INNER JOIN (SELECT `from`, `to`, MAX(sent) maxSent FROM `chat` GROUP BY `from`, `to`
                ) b ON a.`from` = b.`from` AND a.`to` = b.`to` AND a.sent = b.maxSent WHERE a.`to` = $userid ORDER BY a.read ASC,a.sent DESC";            
            $r = mysql_query($q);

Comment: @SirLojik modify the `ORDER BY` into `ORDER BY a.read ASC, a.sent DESC`